# Найти лишний элемент в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Есть массив строк. Все строки одинаковые, кроме одной.

Как ее найти и вернуть?

Пример `function(['privet', 'privet', 'privet', 'poka']) === poka;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как вариантов значений всего два можно пойти следующим путем:

1. взять первые два элемента,
2. если они равны, то простым пробегом по массиву найти элемент, который не будет равен уже найденным.
3. в противном случае, нужно найти первый элемент, который не будет равен одному из указанных.

Реализовать можно следующим образом:

```js
var array = ['privet', 'privet', 'privet', 'poka'];

function findUniq(arr) {
  var prev = arr[0];
  var prev2 = arr[1];
  if (prev == prev2) {
    for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (prev != arr[i]) return arr[i];
    }
  }

  if (prev != arr[2]) return prev;

  if (prev2 != arr[2]) return prev2;
}


console.log(findUniq(array));
```

Comment: тоже подходящий вариант, спасибо

Comment: Всё, теперь понял. Я немного не так понял задачу изначально. Поэтому и решение написал соответствующее, хоть и всё равно подходящее)

Answer (score 3):

Вначале подсчитываем сколько раз в массиве встречается элемент. А потом другим циклом выводим тот элемент, у которого количество равно 1.

```js
var array = ['privet', 'privet', 'privet', 'poka'];

function getSingleElement(array) {
  var counts = {};

  array.forEach(function(element) {
    if (!counts[element]) {
      counts[element] = 0;
    }

    counts[element] += 1;
  });

  for (var item in counts) {
    if (counts[item] == 1) {
      return item;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getSingleElement(array));
```

Comment: в данном случае нет нужды в подсчете, так как всего два значения у строк

Comment: @stranger in the day  это функция var counts = {};?

Comment: И как я сам не додумался, спасибо!

Comment: @DuuudeXX8, нет, это объявление объекта

Comment: @Grundy спасибо

Comment: @Grundy а как лучше? Я почему-то подумал что может быть много разных одинаковых слов кроме одного, которое одно, причем неизвестно какое и его надо найти)